# How to solve the equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 6,\\
 x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 = 10,\\
 x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3 = 18,\\
 x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4 = 34.\end{cases}$

I have found a solution of $(1,1,2,2)$. And I tried to solve it by MAPLE. 
All solutions are in the form of $(1,1,2,2)$ (and any possible arrangement of $(1,1,2,2)$). But how can I prove that the equation has no more solution except these 6 solutions?

How about a general $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$?

$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = a_1,\\
 x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2 = a_2,\\
 x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3 = a_3,\\
 x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4+x_4^4 = a_4.\end{cases}$

Do they have an unique solution? Or not?

Do we have a general method to deal with it?

Comment: It is trivial that Gauss elimination doesn't work.

Comment: You can use Newton's identities to find the elementary symmetric polynomials in the variables. This gives a fourth degree equation whose roots are the values of the variables.

Comment: It follows automatically, from my above comment that the solution is unique upto permutations.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thanks a lot. I've never heard Newton's identities before .  Hence it takes me a lot of time.  So by the Viete's theorem, the elementaary symmetric polynomials in the roots equal to the cofficients. Then it comes to find the cofficients through Newton's identities and  $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$, then solve the new equation, the roots are what I'm searching for.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thanks a lot.

Comment: Newton's identities are a special case of the fact that all symmetric polynomials  are polynomials in the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rene comments, generally speaking, to solve equations of this kind, you should first transform it to
\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = c_1,\\
 x_1 x_2 + x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4 = c_2,\\
 x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4 = c_3,\\
 x_1x_2x_3x_4=c_4.\end{cases}
Then, by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), you immediately get that $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ are $4$ roots of the equation
$$
  (x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4) = x^4-c_1x^3+c_2x^2-c_3x^3+c_4=0
$$
Therefore all your problems are solved.

Comment: Thank a lot. 
I've understood the method.